# Showing both duplicates data?

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

My Data:

[image]

My Code:

```py
DTst = gc.open_by_url('https://xxsxx')

DTsc = DTst.worksheet('Sales1')

DTv = DTsc.get_all_values()

DTv = pd.DataFrame.from_records(DTv[1:], columns=DTv[0])

DTUser = DTv.loc[:, ['Items', 'Amount']]

DTUser.head()
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is,  i want the output to be like in the 2nd image,but right now it called the data from both columns since the column have the same name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `iloc()` function to get specific columns in range.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-first-column-of-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

```
DTv.iloc[:,0:2]
```

looks better approach in this case I think